# Tab Item remains selected WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, tabs

I am using the Tab_SelectionChanged event of TabControl in WPF. It contains 3 tab items. I have to restrict the user to navigate to other tabs i.e Settings and Schedule while work is in-progress on the home tab. While using the event i am facing an issue i.e. If i clicked on settings tab it shows me a popup "You cannot navigate while work is in progress" and when i clicked on schedule tab after clicking on settings tab it shows me the same popup twice. The reason behind this is the Settings tab remains selected.Here is my code for this:

```
private void tabMHPC_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            TabControl tab = (TabControl)sender;
            if (tab.SelectedIndex != -1)
            {
                if (tab.SelectedIndex != 4 && tab.SelectedIndex != 1 && tab.SelectedIndex != 0)
                {
                    if (scanStatus == "fixing")
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(ApplicationInfo.ApplicationName + " is still busy in fixing issues.Please let the fixation complete.", ApplicationInfo.ApplicationName, MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
                        homeTab.IsSelected = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(ApplicationInfo.ApplicationName + " is still busy scanning issues.Please stop it before you leave the Home tab.", ApplicationInfo.ApplicationName, MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
                        homeTab.IsSelected = true;
                    }
                }

                else if (tab.SelectedIndex == 0)
                {

                }
            }
        }
```

I want that previous tab item isSelected property gets false when i move on other tabitem.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of handling the `SelectionChanged` event, you should data bind a property of a suitable type to the [`TabControl.SelectedItem` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selecteditem(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
<TabControl SelectedItem="{Binding YourSelectedItemProperty}" ... />
```

When you do this, you will then be able to stop the `TabItem` being changed:

```
public YourDataType YourSelectedItemProperty
{
    get { return yourSelectedItemProperty; }
    set
    {
        if (isOkToChangeTabItem)
        {
            yourSelectedItemProperty = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("YourSelectedItemProperty");
        }
    }
}
```

The final part  of the solution is to set the `isOkToChangeTabItem` variable to `true` or `false` depending on whether it is OK for the user to change the selected `TabItem` or not.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But i want the the user to click on other tabs and when user move away from one tab to another than the IsSelected property of previously click tab item changes to false.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure why you want to do that, but you're using the wrong approach. You shouldn't be holding references to individual `TabItem`s in the code behind. You should be data binding instead.